# decodeSampledBitmapFromInputStream всегда возвращает null

Tags: android, изображения, bitmap, потоки-данных

Вот я получаю `uri` файла который пользователь выбрал из галереи:

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
 InputStream fileStream = null;
 fileStream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

И хочу сжать картинку, для этого создал класс BitmapLoader,

```
BitmapLoader bitmap = new BitmapLoader();
int size = bitmap.getSampleSizeFromInputStream(fileStream,100,100);

                    imagePhotoFirst.setImageBitmap(
                            bitmap.decodeSampledBitmapFromInputStream(fileStream,size));
```

Вот и сам класс:

```
public class BitmapLoader
{
    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromInputStream(InputStream istream, int sampleSize)
    {
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inSampleSize = sampleSize;
        Bitmap trum= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istream, null, options);
        return trum;
    }

    public static int getSampleSizeFromInputStream(InputStream istream, int reqWidth, int reqHeight)
    {
        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istream, null, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        return calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
    }

    private static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight)
    {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;

        return Math.max(1, Math.max(
                Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight),
                Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth)));
    }
}
```

Так вот он мне всегда возвращает null, почему?( и как это исправить? Я уже переискал много но толком так и не нашёл(

Comment: а вы `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istream, null, options);` проверяли? работает?

Comment: Да, работает. Причина была в другом - я переменную fileStream  использовал несколько раз, А после первого раза она уже стает не рабочая, просто нужно было еще раз вычесть InputStream из uri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, работает. Причина была в другом - я переменную `fileStream` использовал несколько раз, А после первого раза она уже стает не рабочая, просто нужно было еще раз вычесть `InputStream` из `uri`.

Получить `InputStream` из `Uri` можно так:

```
InputStream fileStream = null; 
try { 
fileStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
 } 
catch (IOException e) {
 Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage()); }
```

Comment: `Uri` будет вида "context:\....." Получить из него поток данных можно так:

`InputStream fileStream = null;
try {
    fileStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
}`

Comment: Да, поток "одноразовый", нужно заново открывать после прочтения данных из него.